# Java - Runnable JAR - Notable execution time differences

Tags: java, performance, jar, executable-jar

Recently I've created some tool (Runnable JAR) which is building SQLite database from other txt file. I'm using JRE 1.8.0_20 on all platforms. The fastest program execution is 7min while the lowest 1h 24min. During test, units weren't overloaded by other activities. I've used same base file for testing. The most amazing is for me fact that 4th unit which was quite strong, achieved very poor time.
I'm looking forward for any hints.
Units details below (cannot insert image;/).

**Values:**
TIME, SYSTEM, PROCESSOR, RAM, (Win Experience Index)-> Processor, RAM, Graphic, Graphic in games, Hard drive

1. **7min, Win 7 Profesional 64-bit, Intel Core i3 2120, 3,3GHz, 4GB,(WEI)->7,1 5,9 5,1 5,8 5,9**
2. 10min, Win 7 Home Premium 64-bit, Intel Core i3 M370 2,4GHz, 4GB,(WEI)->6,6 5,9 6,6 6,6 5,9
3. 18min, Win 7 Enterprise 64-bit, Intel Core i5 3320 2,6GHz, 5GB,(WEI)->7,1 5,9 5,0 6,4 6,2
4. **1h 18min, Windows 8 64-bit Intel Core i5 3230, 2,6GHz, 12GB,(WEI)->7,1 7,9 7,7 7,7 5,9**
5. 1h 24 min, Win 7 Profesional 32-bit AMD Athlon 64 x2 Dual Core 6400+ 3,2GHz, 3GB    6,1 6,1 6,8 6,8 5,9

BR,
R4Di

Comment: If you want to include an image, post the link, and than a user with higher rep can include it

Comment: You can use VisualVM to profile the code and get some insights at what is slowing down the process.

Comment: Can you post the code you suspect may be involved? Can you included any profiling information?

Comment: Below you will find image with times-units comparison and screenshots from VisualVM.For sure there is big difference with CPU usage....

TIMES:
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img913/6448/BguV0i.jpg

1st case START:
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/759x442q90/904/BbVcOA.jpg

1st case END:
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/759x441q50/905/43Ngvv.jpg

3rd case:
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/626x376q90/633/y0Ihd9.jpg

4th case START:
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/604x376q90/540/7ahmxY.jpg

4th case END:
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/604x376q90/540/7ahmxY.jpg

Comment: 4th case END (one more time):
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/660x413q90/537/ZkqYiO.jpg